# Topological space of all circles through a point

Tags: general-topology

Consider $S$ the set of all unit circles through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'm trying to understand what this space looks like, assuming we use the obvious topology.

By 'obvious topology' I mean that circles that are close in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are also close in $S$. To formalize that, let's say that for two circles $c_1, c_2 \in S$ we define a metric $d_S(c_1, c_2)$ as e.g. $\max(\max_{p \in c_1} \min_{q \in c_2} d(p, q), \max_{q \in c_2} \min_{p \in c_1} d(q, p))$ with $d$ the standard euclidian metric (that is, find whichever point on $c_1$/$c_2$ is furthest from the other circle) and take the topology induced by $d_S$.

My question is: what does this topological space look like? It is clear to me that we can parametrize it from $S^2 \times S^1$ by first picking the center of our circle (this is the $S^2$) and then rotating it (this is the $S^1$). But it is not at all clear to me that the topological space ends up looking the same.

So what does this topological space look like?

Comment: Do you mean anything specific when you say "look like"? You will probably get better answers if you spell it out.

Comment: Sorry, it's a while since I took topology so I am not that familiar with the language anymore. I am looking for a characterization of the space, e.g. 'yes it's $S^2 \times S^1$' or 'no it's actually $S^2 \times RP^2$'.

Comment: Seems like it is $S^2 \times S^1$. As you've said in your question, consider the point where all of your $S^1$'s should intersect. The centres of all of the $S^1$'s will be a distance of $1$ away from the centre point, and we want to consider *all* such $S^1$'s, so we get $S^2 \times S^1$. We do a similar thing when defining the torus as $S^1 \times S^1$; we want all circles a distance of $1$ away from our "centre torus point", but this time, in only one plane, so we have another $S^1$ in the product, rather than an $S^2$.

Comment: @Clayton Note that the distance between two circles isn't between the two closest points, it is the maximum distance of any point on one of the circles to the other circle (or vice versa).

Comment: I’m sorry, I was reading the wrong space. It is too early in the morning for me haha

Comment: It's  parametrized by pairs $(\pi, P)$ where $\pi$ is a plane through the origin and $P\ne 0$ is a point on it.  Or pairs $(v, w)$, $|v|=1$, $(v,w)=0$. Looks like a tangent bundle minus the zero section.

Comment: I have some drawings on paper that suggest this space is _not_ $S^2 \times S^1$, but I'm not sure how to digitize the :-)

Imagine that V is the set of all unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then a parametrization from $V \times [0, \pi)$ would be to map $(v, \delta)$ to the circle with center $v$, and for $\delta = 0$ pick the circle that lies inside the plane containing the z-axis (and rotate from there as $\delta$ increases).

Then $( (0, 0, 1), 0)$ has arbitrarily close neighbours of the form $(v', \delta)$ for _any_ $\delta$, whereas this is clearly not the case in $S^2 \times S^1$.

Comment: More specifically, if for your parametrization you fix $\delta = 0$, then you get something that isn't really a sphere, the resulting set will have some sort of poles (by the Hairy Ball Theorem :-) ).

Comment: A solid sphere of radius two when taking into account all orientations of all the circles whose locus of centers is a sphere of radius one.

Comment: I think @orangeskid is on the right track, except that the OP wants only unit circles. So it looks to me as if you get the unit sphere subbundle of the tangent bundle.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with tangent bundles (or manifold theory, which is what I get when I Google them), what would be a good place to get started with them? Btw I already noticed that each of my circles is defined by a tangent to the unit sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Every circle is uniquely defined by plane in which it lies and line through its center, so your space $S$ is $\{ l, v \, | \, l \subset v \subset \Bbb R^3\}$, where $l$ is line and $v$ is plane. Most natural way to describe it would be factor $GL(3, \Bbb R)/UT(3, \Bbb R)$, where $UT$ is group of upper-triangular matrices with nonzeroes on diagonal (see [flag variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety)). If you analyze this action and factor, you can conclude that it also can be described as factor of 3-dimensional sphere by free action of [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) embedded into it as subgroup of [SU(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Diffeomorphism_with_S3).